# Swig: Multiple ARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY1 with the same length

Tags: python, swig, cpython

I have a C function that i wish to interface with CPython. the function takes in two pointers and a length. like the following

```
double foo(double ** arr1, double ** arr2, int * length_of_arr1_and_arr2);
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this interface this with swig.

I have tried the following but it did not work.

```
%apply ( double ** ARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY1, int * DIM1 ) {( double ** arr1, int * length_of_arr1_and_arr2), ( double ** arr2, int * length_of_arr1_and_arr2)}
```

Comment: Why is the length given as a pointer and not as just a plain old int by value?

Comment: @Flexo this is because the the arrays are returned. hence the caller needs to know the size of the arrays.

Comment: Make an inline function `void foo2(double** arr1, int* len1, double** arr2, int* len2) {return foo(arr1,arr2,len1);}` and wrap this using two `%apply` statements.

Comment: I was hoping there is a way to  maintain the name of the function @Jens Munk

Comment: There is. Use the %rename functionality afterwards... Everything is done in your .i file